# Как научить FAB плавать при скроллинге GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

Здравствуйте. Я знаю как скрывать `FAB` при прокрутке `ListView`, `RecyclerView`, но не знаю как это реализовать в `GridView`? Кастомный `behavior`? На enSO не нашёл, может плохо искал.

**UPD**

Посмотрел исходный код `GridView`, он наследуется от `AbsListView`. Значит можно юзать способ из `ListView`?

Comment: А Вам принципиально нужен `GridView`? Если Вы знаете как это реализовать в `RecyclerView`, то почему не используете его?

Comment: Чисто для практики. Да, именно `GridView`